# how to know the datatype of an output value in oracle

Tags: oracle, output, sqldatatypes

Suppose I'm running the following query and it gives me the following output:

Query:  `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;`

Output: `29-AUG-16`

As we know SYSDATE returns 'date' type value. But how can I see that datatype on output window?

Suppose when I query with some function say 'type()' `SELECT TYPE(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL` and it will give the datatype of `SYSDATE`

output: `DATE`

Is there any built in methods like this 'type()' or something which will give me the datatype??

N.B. It doesn't have to be `SYSDATE`, it could be any variable or value like `SELECT 'HELLO' FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DUMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm) function:

```
SELECT DUMP(SYSDATE, 1016) FROM DUAL;

Typ=13 Len=8: e0,7,8,1d,b,31,1c,0
```

There data type you can lookup here: [Oracle Built-in Datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#BABCGCHG)

In case you wonder why `Typ=13` does not appear in this table have a look at this: [datatype 13](https://community.oracle.com/thread/660837)

Comment: Just to comment this specific case, you may notice that in-memory DATE representation differs from storage representation (when you dump column value instead of SYSDATE function). In memory is type 13 having 8 bytes and storage type 12 which is just 7 bytes.

Comment: @Domscheit what is this 1016 return_fmt get here? can you explain a little?? or any documentation for the presentation?

Comment: @Hakuna-Matata - If you have access to Google, search for "Oracle dump()" (or even better, after Oracle type your version number, for example in my case I would search for "Oracle 11.2 dump()".) That will take you straight to the documentation.

Comment: I even put a link in my answer to `DUMP` documentation (the blue text)!

Comment: @Domscheit [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm)

Here I got this statement:  "By default, the return value contains no character set information. To retrieve the character set name of expr, add 1000 to any of the preceding format values. For example, a return_fmt of 1008 returns the result in octal and provides the character set name of expr."
I asked about this explanation like here it mentioned about 1008, what it means 1016, where it comes from?? and your 'blue text' doesn't refer to the dump() or what I asked.

Comment: 1016 is 1000 + 16. 16 -> **result in hexadecimal notation**. 1000 -> **retrieve the character set name of expr**. Well, "character set name" is useless on `DATE` type but usually you do not know in advance.